# "Failed to locate libpython within timeout period." When trying to profile a .py file not in a container with pyflame

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling

I am attempting to record hotspots in my code in order to be able to optimize it with multi-threading.

I installed pyflame outside of a container by first running 
  `sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev g++ pkg-config python-dev python3-dev libtool make`
and then I used the **Ubuntu PPA Pre-built Package** by running
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:trevorjay/pyflame`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install pyflame`

**While trying to trace a python command I keep receiving the 
error**
`Failed to locate libpython within timeout period.`
After I get the error, my code runs as normal in the terminal.

My input command is:
`pyflame 30 --threads -t python3 myfile.py`

I am relatively new to Linux, so I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through exactly what I missed and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread: https://github.com/uber/pyflame/issues/151

Python3.7 is not yet supported by pyflame